# How to perform a unittest on a unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

How do you do a unittest on a unittest. I have a unittest and obviously when it is succesfully it generates an ok message in the terminal but I have struggled to find a way of creating a test for the test based upon that.

Basically looking for a way to test if the below test returns ok.

The Test Below:

```
import unittest


class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sum(self):
        self.assertEqual(2+2, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What this returns in the shell :

```
Ran 1 test in 0.000s 
OK
```

Comment: That's already what the test itself does -- if the test fails, it fails, and if it succeeds, it succeeds.  You don't need an extra layer of test that does the exact same thing.  The more useful thing to test a test for is whether it fails under specific conditions (e.g. you can have a test that simulates a bug in the code under test and verifies that your other test catches it).

Comment: You don't test tests - what would be the point? And what would test the test's test and the test test's test??

Comment: There should be no need to test your tests. If there were, then you'd also need to test *those* tests and the cycle would never end. If you write a test that you don't trust then it should be redesigned and/or broken down into smaller pieces such that they become trivial.

Comment: Your test, by the way, doesn't test anything interesting. You don't need to write unit tests for the testing framework itself, unless you are the testing framework developer.

Comment: You mean, like, [mutation tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to have function that does the calculation, so you pass that function to the test case.

Example:

```py
import unittest


# Defined the function that does the calculation
def sum_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y



class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sum(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum_numbers(2, 2), 4)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now this test will evaluate to `ok` and you can add more test to `test_sum`